# Code coverage is not working for some files in WebStorm

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jestjs, webstorm, jetbrains-ide

I want to write a UT for the target code below:

```
// dev code
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import { Dropdown } from 'antd'

import './style.scss'
import classnames from 'classnames'
import Menu from '@lib/Menu'

const DEFAULT_TRIGGER_MODE = 'contextMenu'

interface ContextMenuProps {
  wrapClass?: string
  menu?: { key: string; title: string }[]
  children?: object
  updateMenu?: (event) => { key: string; title: string }[]
  visible?: boolean
  triggerMode?: ('click' | 'hover' | 'contextMenu')[]
}

const updateMenuData =(eventObj, updateMenu, setMenu) => {
  if (updateMenu) {
    const newMenu = updateMenu(eventObj)
    setMenu(newMenu)
  }
}

const populateMenuNodes = (menuData) => {
  if (menuData.length === 0) return <></>

  return (
    <Menu>
      {menuData.map(({ key, title, onClick, disabled }, index) => (
        key === 'menu.divider' ? <Menu.Divider key={key} /> : <Menu.Item key={key} onClick={onClick} disabled={disabled}>{title}</Menu.Item>
      ))}
    </Menu>
  )
}

const ContextMenu: React.FC<ContextMenuProps> = (props) => {
  const [menu, setMenu] = useState(props.menu || [])
  const { children, updateMenu, wrapClass, triggerMode = [DEFAULT_TRIGGER_MODE], ...rest } = props
  return (
    <div
      className={classnames('mstr-as-context-menu', wrapClass)}
      onContextMenu={(e) => {
        updateMenuData(e, updateMenu, setMenu)
      }}
    >
      <Dropdown overlay={populateMenuNodes(menu)} trigger={triggerMode} {...rest}>
        {children}
      </Dropdown>
    </div>
  )
}

export default ContextMenu
```

And I have written a UT for the target code above:

```
import React from 'react'
import {  shallow } from 'enzyme'
import ContextMenu from '../index'

jest.mock('react', () => ({
    ...jest.requireActual('react'),
    useState: jest.fn((menu) => [menu || []]),
}))

describe('ContextMenu/index.js', () => {
    let component
    let props
    beforeEach(() => {
        props = {
            children: <div>Children</div>,
        }
    })

    describe('Check rendered component: ', () => {
        it('should render a component successfully', () => {
            component = shallow(<ContextMenu {...props}/>)
        })
        it('should show Menu.Item', () => {
            props = {
                ...props,
                 menu: [{key: '', title: 'title1'}]
            }
            component = shallow(<ContextMenu {...props}/>)
        });
        it('should show Menu.Divider', () => {
            props = {
                ...props,
                menu: [{key: 'menu.divider', title: 'title1'}]
            }
            component = shallow(<ContextMenu {...props}/>)
        });
        afterEach(() => {
            expect(component).toMatchSnapshot()
        })
    })
})
```

I run the tests successfully.

However I fail to get the coverage data of the target code with WebStorm's Code Coverage feature below.

[image]

From the screenshot below, it seems that WebStorm does not calculate code coverage for the target code while it calculates code coverage for other files.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am the person who proposals the question.

### Investigation

I run the command below in the terminal and find that the code coverage is not calculated for the same files.

```
jest --coverage
```

So it is not a specific issue about WebStorm. It is just an issue about Jest config.

### Solution

Find the Jest config file: jest.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  verbose: true,
  testMatch: ['<rootDir>src/**/*\\.test\\.(ts|tsx|js|jsx)'],
  globals: { __DEV__: true },
  modulePaths: ['./src'],
  moduleFileExtensions: ['ts', 'tsx', 'js', 'jsx', 'json', 'md'],
  moduleNameMapper: {
    '\\.(css|less|scss|gif)$': 'identity-obj-proxy',
    '^.+\\.(css|scss)$': '<rootDir>/node_modules/jest-css-modules',
    '\\.(css|less|scss|sass|gif)$': 'identity-obj-proxy',
    '^antd/es': 'identity-obj-proxy',
    '^@mstr/': 'identity-obj-proxy',
    '^dnd-core$': 'dnd-core/dist/cjs',
    '^react-dnd$': 'react-dnd/dist/cjs',
    '^react-dnd-html5-backend$': 'react-dnd-html5-backend/dist/cjs',
    '^react-dnd-touch-backend$': 'react-dnd-touch-backend/dist/cjs',
    '^react-dnd-test-backend$': 'react-dnd-test-backend/dist/cjs',
    '^react-dnd-test-utils$': 'react-dnd-test-utils/dist/cjs',
    '\\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|eot|otf|webp|svg|ttf|woff|woff2|mp4|webm|wav|mp3|m4a|aac|oga)$': 'identity-obj-proxy',
  },
  testResultsProcessor: './scripts/jest-results-processor.js',
  coverageReporters: ['lcov', 'text', 'json-summary', 'cobertura'],
  setupFiles: ["jest-canvas-mock"],
  setupFilesAfterEnv: ['./jest.setup.js'],
  collectCoverageFrom: [
    'src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}',
    '!src/assets/**/*.{js,jsx,json,ts,tsx}',
    '!src/lib/!(Canvas)/**/*.{js,jsx,json,ts,tsx}',
    '!**/node_modules/**',
    '!**/vendor/**',
    '!**/env/**',
  ],
  testPathIgnorePatterns: ['<rootDir>/src/components/xx/__tests__/data'],
  snapshotSerializers: ['enzyme-to-json/serializer'],
}
```

The key is the code below

```
'!src/lib/!(Canvas)/**/*.{js,jsx,json,ts,tsx}',
```

Change this line to:

```
    'src/lib/**/*.{js,jsx,json,ts,tsx}',
```

So the code coverage of all files, including the files I am working on, under the `lib` directory will be calculated.